# Restore Home Icon on Ubuntu 11.04 Launcher

Tags: 11.04, launcher

After installing Ubuntu 11.04, I removed the Home Icon from the launcher by right clicking on the Home Icon and chosing the - Keep In Launcher option. Then it disappeared. Now I am wondering how do I restore it, because I think it was not a good idea and I need it now. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

Open the launcher i.e. press `super` key and type `nautilus`. You will be presented with home folder open it and on launcher check on `keep in launcher`.

OR

go to `/usr/share/applications/` and drag and drop `nautilus-home.desktop` on the sidebar launcher and check `keep in launcher`